# How can I create a lock for concurrency across different requests (on a process-based webserver)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that people can send data to in the query params of a url. The rails app then validates the correctness of the data and creates a json reponse listing any detected errors. The validation itself is done by checking the data against a set of rules that live in a github repo.

Ideally I'd like to update my local copy of this repo once a day. In order to prevent complications I'd like any requests that come in while this update takes place to back off for a few seconds.

What's the best way to communicate to the incoming requests that an update is currently occuring? I'm using a process based webserver (unicorn), so memory mutexes don't seen like the right answer :(.

Comment: File#flock or an on-disk sempahore file seem like viable options for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far as I've only recently begun work on this. This seemed like it could be a big problem, so I wanted to get some opinions about the best approach. I've seen people talk about File#flock before but I wasn't sure it was the right way for interprocess stuff as I wasn't sure the lock was atomic.

Comment: Would the lockfile gem (https://github.com/ahoward/lockfile) be what I'm looking for in this case then?